# Firebase authorization on .net core

Tags: azure, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using Firebase authentication on my client side (ionic/angular), and am now trying to secure my .NET Core API.

I have it working on localhost, but when I deploy to the API to Azure, it gives me 401s.

I got it working on localhost using this code from https://blog.markvincze.com/secure-an-asp-net-core-api-with-firebase/

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-firebase-project";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-firebase-project",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "my-firebase-project",
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
    });
```

And then in Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Does anyone know why this would fail once I publish it to Azure? The client side works fine, meaning I can log in with facebook and get the correct display name back. But authorized requests to the server fail.

**EDIT: If I set ValidateIssuer=false in the code above, then it works...but I'm guessing this is a big security hole?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your Azure domain to Firebase console (Tab: Authentication >> Authorized Domain)? Photo here: [Firebase add Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds7wI.png)